# How to compare with two array data and chage?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a number array A and a data array B

They just like:

A:

```
[11, 14]
```

B:

```
[
  { title: 'title 1', data: [ { node_id: 11, selected: false }, { node_id: 14, selected: false } ]},
  { title: 'title 2', data: [ { node_id: 70, selected: false } ]}
]
```

My code is like this:

```
B.map((value) => {
  A.map((selectedDeviceId) => {
    value.data.map((valueData) => {
      selectedDeviceId === valueData.node_id
        ? (valueData.selected = true)
        : (valueData.selected = false);
    });
  });
});
```

But when I print B array the result is:

```
[
  { title: 'title 1', data: [ { node_id: 11, selected: false }, { node_id: 14, selected: true } ]},
  { title: 'title 2', data: [ { node_id: 70, selected: false } ]}
]
```

I hope they should be:

```
[ { node_id: 11, selected: true }, { node_id: 14, selected: true } ]
```

What is wrong in my code ?

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do? You've given the inputs, the expected results but we lack information on what the operation is. You've also given the code which doesn't work, so it's a very poor way of trying to figure out what's wrong with it.

Comment: If you're not interested in the return value of `.map()` then `.map()` is not the right tool

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use array `Array.prototype.flatMap()` with `Array.prototype.filter()` method to get the result. Traverse the array using flatMap and then use filter method with `Array.prototype.some()` to filter the node_ids.

```js
const number = [11, 14];
const data = [
  {
    title: 'title 1',
    data: [
      { node_id: 11, selected: false },
      { node_id: 14, selected: false },
    ],
  },
  { title: 'title 2', data: [{ node_id: 70, selected: false }] },
];

const ret = data.flatMap((x) =>
  x.data.filter((y) => number.some((z) => z === y.node_id))
);
console.log(ret);
```

Answer (score 3):

### A clean way of doing it.

```js
const A = [11, 14];

const B = [{
    title: 'title 1',
    data: [{
      node_id: 11,
      selected: false
    }, {
      node_id: 14,
      selected: false
    }]
  },
  {
    title: 'title 2',
    data: [{
      node_id: 70,
      selected: false
    }]
  }
]
const resultList = B.map((_b) => {
  return { ..._b,
    data: _b.data.map(_d => {
      return { ..._d,
        selected: A.includes(_d.node_id)
      }
    })
  }
})
console.log(resultList)
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer?

Answer (score 1):

```js
let A = [11, 14];
let B = [
  { title: 'title 1', data: [ { node_id: 11, selected: false }, { node_id: 14, selected: false } ]},
  { title: 'title 2', data: [ { node_id: 70, selected: false } ]}
];

B.forEach(value => {
  A.forEach(selectedDeviceId => {
  const checkData = value.data.find(v => v.node_id === selectedDeviceId);
  if (checkData) {
    checkData['selected'] = true;
  }
  });
});

console.log(B);
```

Answer (score 1):

@mr hr solution is more succinct but without changing much of what you already have, you should take a second look at your ternary operation. You should edit it to

```js
B.map((value) => {
    A.map((selectedDeviceId) => {
        value.data.map((valueData) => {
          selectedDeviceId === valueData.node_id
            && (valueData.selected = true);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is that you are not using the results of the map() function, you are actually using it incorrectly, it should be:
`.map(value => {return something;})` or `.map(value => something)`

> When not to use map()
>
> Since map builds a new array, using it when you aren't using the
> returned array is an anti-pattern; use forEach or for-of instead.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#When_not_to_use_map)